# How to invoke a C# web service in Salesforce

Tags: c#, web-services, salesforce, apex

I have written a C# web service that queries some data from Salesforce by using Salesforce Web Service API. I want to invoke this web service after an insert process from Salesforce. How can i invoke this web service inside of an Apex trigger ? Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the web sevice inside a method with the @future annotation. Check out this post [HTTP Callout from Triggers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/http-callout-from-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a callout from apex trigger, so you cannot call a .Net web service from apex trigger

But you can create a boolean type field and can create a schedule exe in .net which will run
after every 15 minutes based on boolean field and will update the boolean field to false in saleforce after your web service's code execution.

Comment: I complete my requirement as given Step 1: Create a new boolean field with default value false. Step 2: Update this field to true on before insert of account event of salesforce trigger. Step 3: write a .net exe which will run every 15 minute will look for boolean field for true values Step : Call your web service method in exe Step 5: Set account boolean field to false from exe. It will complete your requirement in asynchronize way.

Comment: How can i change this apex boolean value from .net application ?